# Find the derivative of $f(z) =x^2+iy^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am using  definition of derivative to find derivative of $f(z) =x^2+iy^2$. $$f'(z)=\lim_{\Delta z →0}\frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z}$$  $$f'(z)=\lim_{\Delta z →0}\frac{(x+\Delta x)^2+i(y+\Delta y)^2-x^2-iy^2}{\Delta z}$$
$$f'(z)=\lim_{\Delta z →0}\frac{(2x\Delta x)+(\Delta x)^2+i(2y\Delta y)+i\Delta y^2}{\Delta z}$$
I try to let $\Delta z=\Delta x+i\Delta y$ but I am stuck in the above step. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I suppose that $z$ is supposed to be $x+iy$, that $\text{re}(f(z))=x^2$, and that $\text{im}(f(z))=y^2$, in which case, $f$ is not differentiable by the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations). If your mission is to justify this fact using the definition of the derivative, then I recommend that you examine the limit separately from the real and imaginary directions.

Comment: This function is not complex differentiable, so it is not clear what the question is really asking. Are you supposed to differentiate the map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I am doing a textbook exercise. It first asks using C-R equtaions to find where $f'(z)$ exist and then find its value by definition of derivative.

Comment: Find its value by the definition of the derivative when $f'(z)$ exists. It does not here. The C-R equations tell you that.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin but the answer of this question is $f'(x+ix)=2x$

Comment: Ah, the point is that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold if and only if $z=x(1+i)$. So that's why that's the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that $f(z)=\operatorname{Re}^2(z)+\operatorname{Im}^2(z)i$. You can determine at which points $f$ is differentiable using the Cauchy-Riemann equations. If $x,y\in\Bbb R$, let$$u(x,y)=\operatorname{Re}(f(x+yi))=x^2$$and let$$v(x,y)=\operatorname{Im}(f(x+yi))=y^2.$$Then the Cauchy-Riemann equations are$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}2x=2y\\0=0.\end{array}\right.$$So, since $u$ and $v$ have continuous partial derivatives, if $x_0,y_0\in\Bbb R$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0+y_0i$ if and only if $y_0=x_0$.

It turns out that$$(\forall x_0\in\Bbb R):f'(x_0+x_0i)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,x_0)+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x_0,x_0)i=2x_0.$$This can be proved from the definition of $f'$ as follows: if $x_0\in\Bbb R$, let $z_0=x_0+x_0i$. Then, if $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{z_0\}$,\begin{align}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-2\operatorname{Re}(z_0)&=\frac{x^2+y^2i-x_0^{\,2}-x_0^{\,2}i}{x-x_0+(y-x_0)i}-2x_0\\&=\frac{x^2-x_0^{\,2}+(y^2-x_0^{\,2})i}{x-x_0+(y-x_0)i}-2x_0\\&=\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-x_0)^2i}{x-x_0+(y-x_0)i}.\end{align}Given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\frac\varepsilon2$. If $|z-z_0|<\delta\left(=\frac\varepsilon2\right)$, let $\eta=|z-z_0|$. Then you have $|\operatorname{Re}(z)-x_0|,|\operatorname{Im}(z)-x_0|\leqslant\eta$, and therefore\begin{align}\left|\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-2\operatorname{Re}(z_0)\right|&=\left|\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-x_0)^2i}{x-x_0+(y-x_0)i}\right|\\&\leqslant\frac{2\eta^2}\eta\\&=2\eta\\&<2\delta\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}And this proves that$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-2\operatorname{Re}(z_0)=0.$$In other words,$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=2\operatorname{Re}(z_0)=2x_0.$$